# I may get caught cheating on my finances exam

Tags: cheating

Long story short I just had two exams - one after the other.

One required me to use LockDown Browser and the other one was in CANVAS. The second class is Finances and I asked a friend who already graduated from the same campus on Finances to help me out answer some questions.

With that being said, the final question allowed us to attach a file with the procedure and I sent a PDF file of the excel sheet.

The excel file has my friend as an author and I completely forgot to change/remove such a basic thing- later on there is a modification done by me.

I sent an email right away after noticing the pdf was a mess just to notice the author thingy. I tried recalling the email but hey, 2021 and we still cannot edit tweets nor delete sent emails. I sent like two additional emails explaining that I messed up not adding my name on it and bla bla bla.

Additional information. Teacher asked us to join the zoom meeting via phone and record our screen, hands and desk at ALL-TIME.

Update: Teacher just replied to the email with the correct file that has name and no friend author.

In case, just in case the teacher finds out about the author what could be a good excuse?

"Teacher I had an exam before this one that required me to use Lockdown and my friend's laptop already had it so I proceeded to do the exam in the same laptop"

"Teacher at that time my friend was at my house- my laptop had a BSOD so I proceeded to use his laptop"

"Teacher I visited my friend and had no laptop- proceeded to use his and do the exam"

I am so nervous- I am such an idiot because I graduate next semester... way to freaking go and messing up things. Finally, I would also like to add that the teacher said "it is not necessary to upload any file but if you want to overview something then you won't be able to".

I simply do not what to think, do or say... I am shocked and worst thing is that they upload grades this weekend but I have classes with her once a week (THU). Also my friend lives like 3 hours away from me.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to immediately contact the professor right away and inform them about what has happened. You’re better off being up front about it as opposed to being perceived to have cheated, in which case, it goes through the system and it’s so much worse for you.

Its better to communicate then to be perceived as a cheater. You may have to rewrite the exam or have the weight moved, but that’s all better then being accused of cheating. Because when you get accused of cheating, it’s a big deal, and often it goes outside of the profs jurisdiction and up the chain until it doesn’t.

I’m not sure how it is elsewhere, but at my institution, if you get accused of cheating then the burden is on you to prove your innocence.

It’s hard to tell if you did cheat based on how sporadic your post is. But if you did in fact cheat, well, best of luck.

Comment: The guy isn’t being “perceived as a cheater.” They cheated. It’s in the title, and all through his confusing and confused description.

Comment: Yeah the writing was bad enough it actually confused me a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

tl,dr:
Do you feel you cheated? then ask to cancel your exam attendance and retake it at the next session. You will not graduate next semester, but you will avoid having a guilty conscience for the rest of your life (or you may just "jump on the dark side" and good luck with your life).

long answer:
Did you ever check the author of the powerpoint files of your classes? you may have had some **BIG** surprises.

I do not get your point: you were not required to upload a file, you still uploaded it.
Have you had this file in advance before the exams? it is not like your friend was sitting with you (even remotely) during the exams, right?

The first university opened in the year 1088. In the year 1089 there were already notes and exercises solved from the exams of previous year. Without Excel/word/stackoverflow/etcetc.
From what you describe, you did not cheat, you just employed this very old technique of looking into past exams to pass future exams.

It's a technique that teaches nothing (especially finances, **past performance is NOT indicative of future results** is the ass-saving phrase every financial product has in its marketing material!) but it is quite productive in passing poorly-designed exams.

Anyhow

> I sent like two additional emails
> explaining that I messed up not adding my name on it and bla bla bla.

it's a text-book example of [Excusatio_non_petita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excusatio_non_petita,_accusatio_manifesta). Receiving such a mail I would have a big laugh. Then I would think I would fail you because you are clearly trying to save your ass from some form of cheating. Then I would think that if I mark negatively your exam, although your answers were correct, you will sue me, on the basis I was unfair in the evaluation of your exam and I prevented you from graduating and damages and carreer prospect and etcetc ...  so after the big laugh, I would report your exam as possible cheating and good luck with your graduation. I would do this, unless you strongly ask to retake it at the next session. Then I would be okay with that, and I would hope that you would learn a thing or two about informatics, instead of complaining about emails that cannot be recalled.